# How do you define a p.d.f and c.d.f for a random variable that realises real values from real line with no bias?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Basically assume that it is given to you that random variable X outputs real values in **R** and each value is equilikely. Then how could it's p.d.f and c.d.f be defined. Also once that is done for **R**, then can it we done for set of all integers as well i.e. **Z**

Comment: continuous rv cannot take on any finite value with meaningful probability. also not sure if it is even possible, perhaps consider $X_n$ with pdf $f_n(x) = \mathbb{I}(x \in [-n,n]) /(2n)$?

Answer (score 0):

A positive, non-zero and translation-invariant measure on the Borel subsets of $\Bbb R$ cannot be finite, so there is no translation-invariant Borel probability $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we could do this, but it's impossible.

For $\Bbb Z$ it's easy to see: if $p$ is the probability of choosing any integer $n$, then (by countable additivity) the sum of the probabilities over all integers $n$ would either be $0$ (if $p=0$) or $\infty$ (if $p>0$), both of which contradict the fact that the total probability must equal $1$.

For $\Bbb R$ it's a little harder to see, since there are uncountably many possible values. However, presumably such a random variable would give equal probability $p$ to each of the intervals ..., $[-1,0)$, $[0,1)$, $[1,2)$, ...; and then the same contradiction can be reached as above.